# Information on this large beige motor w/battery box?

Tags: part-identification, motor, creator

I have a LEGO Technic motor with a built in battery box for x3 "AA" batteries (thus 4.5 volts). Could you help me identify it? What set does it belong to and how old is it? Colours are beige and green/grey. Has a red light on top and a white round brick which serves as a control switch. There is a on-off switch at the base, and the numbers 3393 are found at the base.

[image]

Comment: The white round brick isn't part of this piece and can be taken off.

Answer (score 11):

It's the main module from Record and Play (set [4095](http://brickset.com/sets/4095-1/Record-and-Play)):

[image: 4095]

This part was only included in this set released in 2003. The part contains several motors and some electronics that allow you to record motor movements and then play them back.

[image]

Pressing the red button would let you record movements for a maximun of 20 seconds by adjusting the motors and the green button would play back the last recorded movement.