# What is this brick and how do I use it?

Tags: part-identification

My son received a huge assortment of legos for his birthday and one piece we would like to know how to use, but I can't seem to find information on it anywhere! I would sure appreciate any help you fine folks might be able to offer. I am not able to share my picture because it's too big. The part I'm talking about is [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lego-2002-sand-gray-battery-powered-piece-lights-sound-4213-replacement-works/293037939131?hash=item443a6c19bb:g:aHEAAOSwT8JaynPT). The only words or numbers I can find on ours is "2002 lego group" and the numbers "2223". Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is

- Record and Play Module, 16 x 10 x 4 with Built-in Motors 4.5V (Item No: 3173c01)

[image]

[image]

Comment: There was another question on our site asking about the same exact part. It has more information on how to use it.

Comment: This is a better answer: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/6659/15028

Comment: Also, the OP *already knew* what part it was, she didn't know how to use it which is what she was pretty much asking. So I don't think this will answer her question.

Comment: Thank you. And no, I had no idea what part it was OR how to use it. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: @JessikaMcNaughton, You can also download a PDF of the sets instructions from LEGO.com from [here](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/4235969.pdf).